# Tornado : How to properly close IOLoop with websocket?

Tags: python, tornado

I try to make some pretty nice things with Tornado in Python.

I have several threads with theses functions (simplified) :

```
def run(self):
    self.io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()
    self.io_loop.make_current()
    self.io_loop.add_callback(self.func)

    self.io_loop.start()
    self.io_loop.close()

async def func(self):
    request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(...)
    self.client = await tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(request, on_message_callback=func_msg, ping_interval=num, ping_timeout=num2)

def stop(self):
    self.io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(self.client.close)
    self.io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(self.io_loop.stop)
```

I start theses threads : the function run is executed. Everything go well, I receive the message.
But when I want to stop, the io_loop.close() raises some errors : "Task was destroyed but it is pending".
It seems some websockets are looping to receive messages, but I destroyed them before...

I tried to cancel the pending tasks with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The `IOLoop` must be stopped before it is closed; this means that `IOLoop.stop()` must be called before calling `IOLoop.close()`. Typically, the call to `close()` will be after the call to `start()` (rather than the call to `stop()`) to allow the call to `start()` to return before closing.

https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html

Comment: Yes. The function stop() calls the IOLoop.stop() and permits the call to IOLoop.close().

Comment: @Hirisar but in your code `close()` is called before `stop()` when it should be `stop()` called before `close()`.

Comment: Not that case. In stop(), the close() function shuts the websocket, not the IOLoop.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write how do you call `stop()` so I assume you call it from signal handler right? To me it looks like you have a race condition in:

```
    self.io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(self.client.close)
    self.io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(self.io_loop.stop)
```

- the order of execution may not be the same as the order they are defined.

Also, the docs say: `This method is suspected to have been broken since Tornado 5.0`: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback_from_signal